# Magento configured to use SOLR, but it seems to skip it

Tags: search, magento, solr, enterprise

We are using Magento Enterprise Edition, versio 1.10.1.1. I installed SOLR, which is working fine, and configured Magento to use SOLR. When I push the button "TEST CONNECTION" in the Magento admin, it is succesfull. I do see in the SOLR log files that Magento sends the ping command to SOLR.

Now when I try to actually search something on the website, the search query doesn't reach SOLR. I don't see the select request coming in.

When I do a search query directly to the SOLR engine, I do see the query logged, so it seems to me that SOLR is running fine.

Magento must be falling back to mysql search. But why? How can I debug this? What files are responsible for doing the actual request to SOLR?

All caching has been disabled in Magento.

Comment: you are using EE version, have you tried to ask from your paid support directly from Magento :)

Comment: I'll try, but I am afraid they will tell me that SOLR is independend software which isn't covered by the included support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were experiencing the same problem a few days ago. We found out that one of our extensions was preventing Magento to use SOLR. So you should check whether your extensions are rewriting the search or making changes to it.

Comment: Would you like to share what plugin was conflicting with the SOLR search in your case?

Comment: You we're right. In my case the Amasty Improved Navigation was conflicting with SOLR. I downgraded to the version that we used in our 1.8.0.0 which was probably modified by developers. This works.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it. I can't tell you which extension was in our case, there were so many that we finally decided to start from the scratch.

Comment: @rolandow where to change the code can u provide please send a link.

Comment: @ravipatel sorry i don't work on that project anymore, and I don't have the source code either. I'd think the plugin should be compatible by now. Otherwise drop Amasty an e-mail.